# Get Bluetooth Hotspot Device IPs in Android 10

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-10.0, tethering

I need to get the IP of a device that is on the bluetooth tethering hotspot.

In Android 9 and below, I could get the ARP table by doing the following:

```
    var fileReader = new FileReader("/proc/net/arp");
    var bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
```

However, since Android 10 update, the above throws an exception

```
Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/arp: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I believe this is due to the new Scoped Storage feature.
Many internet blogs believe that adding `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to the application tag in the manifest will fix that, however it did not.

I can't find any other way to get the IP of a connected device.

Is there any way to do this in Android 10?

Comment: Have you found any solution? I guess we need to add some permission..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android 10+, due to [privacy changes in Android 10](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#proc-net-filesystem), it is impossible to read the "/proc/net/arp" file.

It is not a question of enabling some sort of permission.